# Cannot access Sylius admin or view styled login, register or account pages

Tags: symfony, sylius, symfony-cmf

I'm looking to use Sylius for a new e-commerce site and wanted to have a play around first as it looks awesome but after installing all seems to work well on the front end but as soon as I view the login or register page, any kind of template or styling is missing. In fact there are no stylesheets or Javascript files set. All that appears are the raw unstyled forms and literally nothing else.

[image: a baron login page]
[image: a baron register page]

If I try to log in using the credentials at the end of the app/console sylius:install step, I receive the following error:

> "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("None of the chained routers were able to generate route: Route 'cmf_create_put_document_base' not found") in CmfCreateBundle::includejsfiles-create.html.twig at line 17.”

If I complete an order as a new customer and then view my account all I see printed to my screen is who I’m logged in as together with my username and email address and a logout link. That’s it.

[image: a baron account page]

Given I’ve had a play with the demo at http://demo.sylius.org/ this is not how I see it working.

If I grep the dev.log file, I find the following errors in addition to the one mentioned above:

> [2014-12-11 10:07:29] assetic.ERROR: The template "CmfCreateBundle::includejsfiles-hallo-coffee.html.twig" contains an error: Unable to find file "@CmfCreateBundle/Resources/public/vendor/hallo/src/hallo.coffee". [] []
>   [2014-12-11 10:07:29] assetic.ERROR: The template "CmfCreateBundle::includejsfiles-ckeditor.html.twig" contains an error: Unable to find file "@CmfCreateBundle/Resources/public/vendor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js". [] []

If I look for the paths @CmfCreateBundle/Resources/public/vendor/hallo/src/hallo.coffee or @CmfCreateBundle/Resources/public/vendor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js I can verify they don’t exist in the vendor/symfony-cmf/create-bundle/Resources/public/vendor/ directory.

Install steps are:

- composer create-project -s dev sylius/sylius-standard:v0.11.0 www, also tried composer
- create-project -s dev sylius/sylius-standard www
- cd www
- chmod -R 775 web/media/ app/cache app/logs
- chmod 664 app/configs/parameters.yml
- composer run-script post-install-cmd as step 1 fails when trying to clear cache
- app/console sylius:install with fixtures added

Of note, I’ve tried installing on VMWare (Ubuntu 12.04, PHP5.5) and an Amazon EC2 instance (Ubuntu 14.04, PHP5.6) and while I’m familiar with PHP and ZF2, I have zero Symfony 2 or Sylius experience.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i have install fresh sylius but in admin panel css is not load? any idea please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I couldn't get v0.11 working to get to the backend, installing v0.12, which was has just been released has resolved the issue. See more at http://sylius.org/blog/sylius-0-12-0-with-faceted-search.

Answer (score 3):

I also just experienced this issue. To resolve it, simply add the following line to `app/config/routing.yml`:

```
symfony_cmf:
    resource: @CmfCreateBundle/Resources/config/routing/rest_no_locale.xml
```

I'm investigating why the install didn't take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the steps here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/create/introduction.html#installation

Answer (score 0):

I followed @avolkman trick with adding a routing rule:

```
symfony_cmf:
    resource: @CmfCreateBundle/Resources/config/routing/rest_no_locale.xml
```

But this only fixed problem with missing js files but not fixed problem with missing template on login page.

I'm using new version 0.12 (Sylius Standard) and still have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error :

```
php app/console cmf:create:init-hallo-devel
```

clear the cache or remove it as usual

```
php app/console ca:c --env=prod and php app/console ca:c
```

rebuild assets (you'll see now hallo-coffee.js)

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

Done ! No more errors